# How to Serve Static Files in Apache Superset Backend Rnnning Locally Without Docker

Tags: apache-superset, static-files

I'm working on a project in Apache Superset which is running locally without docker and I'm having trouble serving static files such as images, stylesheets, and JavaScript files for superset flask backend running on http:127.0.0.1:8088 but all assets are loadingon frontend side running on http:127.0.0.1:9000

I don't know what to do on backend side but on frontend side was working fine i also created build on frontend side so see i this resolves the issue but no use